# One email address recognized as spam

Tags: email, thunderbird, spf

Emails send from some of the addresses in one domain are marked as spam by multiple email clients. Since just few addresses within the domain are marked as spam, I do not think it is a domain problem, or can it be?

I checked the email header, but do not have any experience with this and I don't know what to do next:

**Thunderbird**

```
X-Spam-Flag: YES X-Spam-Score: 6.63 X-Spam-Level: ******
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=6.63 tagged_above=-10 required=5
    tests=[ALL_TRUSTED=-1, BAYES_00=-1.9, DNS_FROM_AHBL_RHSBL=2.699,
    HTML_MESSAGE=0.001, RCVD_IN_PBL=3.335, RCVD_IN_RP_RNBL=1.31,
    RCVD_IN_SORBS_DUL=0.001, RDNS_NONE=0.793,
    SHORT_HELO_AND_INLINE_IMAGE=1.39, URIBL_BLOCKED=0.001] autolearn=no
```

**Yahoo**

```
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 217.11.253.114

Received-SPF: none (domain of "ourdomain" does not designate permitted sender hosts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the example of E-mail header you gave us.

The e-mail scored `6.63` most of which comprised by:

`DNS_FROM_AHBL_RHSBL=2.699` - this means your e-mail tested positive the Abusive Host Blocking List test.

`RCVD_IN_PBL=3.335` - per [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/RCVD_IN_PBL) the e-mail was received via a relay in Spamhaus PBL.

`RCVD_IN_RP_RNBL=1.31` - per [this page](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/RCVD_IN_RP_RNBL) the last external relay in the Received chain was listed in the DNSBL Return Path Reputation Network Blacklist (RNBL).

`RDNS_NONE=0.793` - per [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/RDNS_NONE) the e-mail was delivered to trusted network by a host with no rDNS.

---

The receiving host determened this email is a spam because it scored 6.63 points while threshold is 5 (see the`required=5` in the header).

Now, `DNS_FROM_AHBL_RHSBL=2.699` is not your fault - per their [announcement](http://www.ahbl.org/content/changes-ahbl) the system was shut down and should not be used anymore.

In regadrs to rest of the points - they could be valid and your e-mail relay or e-mail relay which happened to participate to your e-mail routing could actually be listed in blacklists.

`RDNS_NONE=0.793` could be fixed by creating a PTR DNS record for the e-mail relay.

As I [explained](https://superuser.com/a/632571/238539) earlier this sort of spam detection is based on semi-arbitrary scale and evaluation happens at the receiving mail server. It is very possible to get these settings wrong and as result get legitimate e-mails marked as spam.

In this case one obvious reason - receiving system is using Abusive Host Blocking List which was shut down and as result it **could** score your e-mail with more points (false positive).

If you search Internet for `DNS_FROM_AHBL_RHSBL` you will find many people facing same problem.

The owner of the remote email server should stop using this system, then even without further actions spam score for this particular e-mail would drop below the threshold and it will not be considered spam anymore.

You can further drop potential spam score by creating PTR DNS record for your e-mail gateway and by removing your mail servers from blacklists (if they are listed).

Answer (score 0):

Probably a domain problem.

Check this tool http://viewdns.info/ in the box that says **"SPAM Database Lookup"** to verify if the domain is in a database of known spammers.

Comment: 217.11.253.114 is **not listed** ...